How to identify the child elements of <form> with Playwright?
I would like to know if there is a way to get all of the child elements for an HTML Form.
For example, HTML:
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

In this case I would expect to get the three input elements.
I'm trying:
for element in await page.locator('form').all():
   print(element)

But I get:
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='``https://alexguemez.com/``'> selector='form >> nth=0'\>

.all() is generally poor practice because it doesn't auto wait. What action are you really trying to take here? As answers describe, you're selecting forms, not inputs within forms.

I think you missunderstand how the .all() method works in your code. In Playwright, page.locator('form') returns a locator object, which is a reference to the form element(s) in the DOM. Calling .all() on a locator does not return all the child elements; instead, it resolves to a list of locators that match the initial selector.
In your case, await page.locator('form').all() is returning a list containing the form element(s) rather than the child elements within the form.
see offical docs
Unfortunatly, I don't have an env to try right now, but I would try something like
form_children = page.locator('form >> *').all()
for element in form_children:
    # operate with the element here


The locator identifier has to be change from form
to form > input
for element in await page.locator('form > input').all():
              print(element)

